# Create a Java for loop to concatenate 2 sets of strings

Tags: java, string, list, for-loop, dictionary

I have 
`Map<String, String> prefixes`

and
`List<String> annotationProperties`

And I am trying to get the string output of
`prefix: annotationProperty`
for each entry (they were entered in order).

Is there a for loop I could use to concatenate these? I need to return the entries as a `List<String>` to use in an XML output.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a sample?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking; you want to take each item in `annotationProperties` and create a list of strings with the item and that key's value in `prefixes`?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of inputs and expected output?

Comment: Are you generating XML using string concatenation?

Comment: I am in Java 8 and I'm using StringBuilder. I want to just concatenate the prefix with it's annotation property. So, the input would be something like a list of prefixes {"owl","rdf","xds"} (which is actually a Map) and a list of annotation properties {"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#","http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#","http://www.w3.org/2000/01/XMLSchema#"}. The output I want is {"owl : http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#", etc...}

Answer (score 1):

I assume `annotationProperties` is a key for `prefix` map. If that is the case then in Java 8 you can do this:

```
List<String> output = annotationProperties.stream()
        .map(prop -> String.format("%s: %s",  prefix.get(prop), prop))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`stream` is called so you can use stream functions such as `map` and `collect`

`map` is called to transform the strings in `annotationProperties` into your desired output

and `collect` is called to convert the stream back into a list

---

If you want to use a for loop then you could also do it like this:

```
// The end size is known, so initialize the capacity.
List<String> output = new ArrayList<>(annotationProperties.size());
for (String prop : annotationProperties){
    output.add(String.format("%s: %s",  prefix.get(prop), prop));
}
```

---

> Can a set a variable equal to `.collect(Collectors.toList());` ?

We already have one! In both cases we made a variable `output` which is a list of Strings formatted as `prefix: property`. If you want to use this list then you can loop over it like this:

```
for (String mystring : output) {
    // do xml creation with mystring
}
```

or like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++){
    String mystring = output.get(i);
    // do xml creation with mystring
}
```

or like this:

```
output.stream().forEach(mystring -> {
    // do xml creation with mystring
});
```

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I should have been more specific about the annotationProperties. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: One more question - if I wanted to use this output in a for loop to add into my XML, how would I call the result? Can a set a variable equal to .collect(Collectors.toList()); ?

Comment: Much appreciated. Unfortunately, this is returning empty... Tried a few different things here and it doesn't seem to like it.